# C# Instantiate and add Values to Nested List in Model

Tags: c#, list, nested, nested-lists

I have a unit test class where I am doing some testing on a factory. In this unit test I mock some data. In the mocked data I have the NumberModel (parent model) inside the NumberModel I have a nested list of models called ReferenceModel. I have instantiates many lists while adding values to them all on the same line, but when I tried to do this with my nested list of models I found that I could not.

Here is a snippet from the unit test class where I am mocking my data.

```
_numberModel = new NumberModel()
{
   value1 = 1,
   value2 = x,
   referenceList = new List<ReferenceModel> { ID = 55, NumberType = Mean } < -- These show undefined
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to drill down to the nested list in the parent model, so that the nested list of models are defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing up collection initializers and object initializers. The code

```
new List<ReferenceModel> { foo }
```

Does this:

```
var list = new List<ReferenceModel>();
list.Add(foo);
```

So you need to instantiate a `ReferenceModel`:

```
new List<ReferenceModel> { new ReferenceModel { ID = 55, NumberType = Mean } }
```

Comment: I looked and could not find any posts or examples, but maybe my search query was not correct.

Answer (score 3):

When initializing a list, you have to initialize each item separately:

```
_numberModel = new NumberModel()
{
   value1 = 1,
   value2 = x,
   referenceList = new List<ReferenceModel> { 
           new ReferenceModel {ID = 55, NumberType = Mean} 
       }
};
```

The syntax you use works well for arrays of native types (double, ints), but not classes with properties.